# Obj-c, can I use a protocol as a type of parameter for function arguments?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, touch, protocols

I’m create a cocoa touch framework to share some common code between my apps.

I need to pass an instance of a class into a method, which has some specific properties.

The method will be called from the app.

I’m quite new to using protocols.

Should I create a protocol h file in my framework with all the properties required by the function.

If so can I pass the protocol as the type of the instance variable into the function?

If not how can achieve this?

Comment: In simpler terms you could say I want to pass a model into the function which is in a class within a framework. I need to be able to create a class in my app which can use the model

Comment: Every delegate property you find in iOS and AppKit are examples of methods that accept protocols. Examples: `UITableView dataSource`. This gives the method `setDataSource:(id<UITableViewDataSource>)delegate`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can. Here's an example.

First, declare your protocol in a `.h` file:

```
@protocol Vehicle <NSObject>

@property NSNumber * numberOfWheels;

@required
-(void)engineOn;

@end
```

Declare the classes which conform to your protocol:

```
#import "Vehicle.h"

@interface Car : NSObject <Vehicle>

@end
```

Implement the required methods and synthesise the properties:

```
@implementation Car
@synthesize numberOfWheels;

-(void)engineOn {
    NSLog(@"Car engine on");
}

@end
```

and another, for the sake of example:

```
#import "Vehicle.h"

@interface Motorcycle : NSObject <Vehicle>

@end

@implementation Motorcycle
@synthesize numberOfWheels;

-(void)engineOn {
    NSLog(@"Motorcycle engine on");
}

@end
```

When you declare a method which you want to accept a `Vehicle` argument, you use the generic `id` type and specify that any object passed in should conform to `Vehicle`:

```
#import "Vehicle.h"

@interface Race : NSObject

-(void)addVehicleToRace:(id<Vehicle>)vehicle;

@end
```

Then, in the implementation for that method, you can use the properties and methods declared in the protocol, regardless of the concrete type that has been passed in:

```
@implementation Race

-(void)addVehicleToRace:(id<Vehicle>)vehicle {
    [vehicle engineOn];
}

@end
```

Then, as you'd expect, you can pass in instances of concrete classes that conform to your protocol:

```
Motorcycle *cycle = [[Motorcycle alloc] init];
cycle.numberOfWheels = 2;
Car *car = [[Car alloc] init];
car.numberOfWheels = 4;
Race *race = [[Race alloc] init];
[race addVehicleToRace:car];
[race addVehicleToRace:cycle];
```

And the appropriate concrete implementation of the protocol's methods will be executed, depending on the actual concrete types that you pass as a parameter:

```
2018-10-15 13:53:45.039596+0800 ProtocolExample[78912:1847146] Car engine on
2018-10-15 13:53:45.039783+0800 ProtocolExample[78912:1847146] Motorcycle engine on
```

Comment: Can you add some properties to the protocol please?

Comment: Sure have added. It's very simple; just declare property in the protocol and make sure to synthesize them in classes that conform to the protocol (they won't be automatically synthesized).

Comment: Looks good, I think, I just want to implement this today before accepting. I’m actually going to use something like “vehicle” as a protocol on my app delegate to pass some settings into my framework. I didn’t want to define the structure of my app delegate properties outside of the framework. Sounds like this should all work.

Comment: To be fair, your question was about how to work with protocols as arguments to methods, not about your specific use case. Perhaps at least a vote up for effort?

Comment: Sure. I’m sure this will all work out, I just want to try it.

Comment: I’m still happy to accept, if you think I should be doing something different, if you’d like to suggest?

Comment: Well, that's a completely different question, and it's not clear exactly what you're trying to achieve (and the comments aren't really an appropriate place to answer anyway). The best thing to do would be to have a go at your implementation and then ask another question if you run into some specific problems. Whether you accept the answer or not is completely up to you, no problem at all if you want to accept it later.